# Show average build / release times in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

What is the suggested way to find / display the average build and release (rather deployment) times within VSTS.

The reason for this is to be able to find out which ones are taking longer than I'd like so that I can cut down the time taken. I don't want to have to manually click into each and every build and deployment to have to find the information.

Other than writing a script to hit the API I am not sure what other options I have available to me.

Comment: What's the average build/release time do you mean? Is it average time for all the builds belong to a build definition, or all the builds accross all the build definitions etc? Besides, from average time, you can not "find out which ones are taking longer".

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Ideally I'd prefer to see times of all builds across all build definitions but seeing them for a single build definition would be enough. If the averages were from the last n number of builds it would definitely be useful in finding where time was being spent.

Comment: I add the answer to calculate the verage build time by REST API, and you can have a try. And one thing just to be neted: if the build definition was updated (such as add and remove some tasks) during queuing the n's builds, the average build time seems haven't much significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get last n builds from a build definition, you can follow below steps:

1. Get the buildId of the n’s builds separately

   You can use [List builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/builds/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) REST API to get the n’s builds:

   ```
   GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitionId}&$top={n}&api-version=4.1
   ```
2. Get the Timeline for each build

   To get the timeline for a build, you can use Build [Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/timeline/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) REST API:

   ```
   GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline?api-version=4.1
   ```

   For the build time of a build, it’s `(last task finishTime) – (first task startTime)`. And you can get the total build time of the n’s builds by sum each build time.
3. Calculate the average build time

   After get the total build time, then you can get the average build time for the n’s builds.

For average release time you can use the similat method.